# How to stop the stepper line from extending when it is at the end of the step

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my stepper line. I wanted that at the end of the step it won't extend another line. And I want it that at the end of the step it will stop from extending it's line. Below is the image and the codes that I am trying to implement.
[Here is the image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Dih.png)

```
                &:first-child {
                    ._schedule-item {
                        &:after {
                            display: none;
                        }
                    }
                }

                &:last-child {
                    .schedule-item {
                        &:after {
                            display: none;
                        }
                    }
                }

                ._stepper {
                    background-color: rgb(38,170,224);
                    border: 3px solid rgb(38,170,224);
                    border-radius: 100%;
                    width: 7px;
                    height: 7px;

                    &:after {
                        content: "";
                        position: absolute;
                        width: 1px;
                        position: absolute;
                        height: 100px;
                        background-color: rgb(38,170,224);
                        left: 29.5px;

                    }
                }
```

Comment: pls share html and css code.. with output

Answer (score 0):

```
._stepper:last-child:after{
      display: none;
 }
```

Make the steppers last child after to display none

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use opacity to hide than display:none

```
 ._stepper {
     &:last-child {
         &::after {
             opacity: 0;
         }
    }
}
```